# Helper method within each do loop not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a loop that looks like this

```
<% @user.collections.each do |collection| %>
       <h1 class="impact"> <%= collection.name %><br></h1>
        <%=  collection.stories.count %>
<% end %>
```

It works perfectly to show the Collections that belongs to a User, and then show how many Stories are in each Collection.

However, I want to use a helper that does this.

in the view

```
<% @user.collections.each do |collection| %>
       <h1 class="impact"> <%= collection.name %><br></h1>
        <%=  number_of_stories_in_collection %>
<% end %>
```

in the helper

```
module CollectionsHelper 
    def number_of_stories_in_collection
        collection.stories.count
    end

    def render_stories_count
      if number_of_stories_in_collection.zero?
        'No stories in this collection yet'
      else
        "#{number_of_stories_in_collection} #{'story'.pluralize(number_of_stories_in_collection)}"
      end
    end
end
```

I get an error that says

```
undefined method `stories' for #<Collection::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f510f504af8>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: add a `byebug` in your helper and see why and what you receiving in `number_of_stories_in_collect` hint: it is receiving activerecord array instead of single collection

Comment: I did that but byebug doesn't tell me what's the problem.

Comment: `byebug` doesn't tell you what's the problem is, it provides a debugging console at the exact line where you put it so you can check for objects and their values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extending @Richard's answer and little bit of optimisation to avoid n+1 queries..

```
<% @user.collections.includes(:stories).each do |collection| %>
  <h1 class="impact"> <%= collection.name %><br></h1>
  <%=  render_stories_count(collection) %>
<% end %>
```

helper:

```
module CollectionsHelper
  def number_of_stories_in(collection)
    collection.stories.length
  end

  def render_stories_count(collection)
    if (count = number_of_stories_in(collection)).zero?
      'No stories in this collection yet'
    else
      "#{count} #{'story'.pluralize(count)}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I got wrong argument type Symbol (expected Module) on this line <% @user.collections.include(:stories).each do |collection| %>. Any idea why?

Comment: it should be `includes` and not `include`, my bad check updated anser

Comment: Thanks, no errors when I run it but the numbers are displayed as "5" rather than "5 stories" now.

Comment: that's bound to happen, I thought you knew that. anyway.. you need to call `render_stories_count(collection)` instead of `number_of_stories_in(collection)`.

Comment: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) on the line def render_stories_count

Comment: really? did you write exactly as given above?

Comment: yes direct copy paste, I can't seem to identify the issue either.

Comment: I doubt, please check again since I edited it couple of times. helper method is execting `collection`. or maybe you have same method name multiple times

Comment: had same method name used elsewhere I forgot to remove. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

The 'collection' variable isn't an instance variable, so the helper can't see it.

Change your view to this:

```
<% @user.collections.each do |collection| %>
   <h1 class="impact"> <%= collection.name %><br></h1>
    <%=  number_of_stories_in(collection) %>
<% end %>
```

And your helper method to:

```
def number_of_stories_in(collection)
    collection.stories.count
end
```

This way you are passing the variable to the helper correctly.